# What is the proper format/contents of a software ARCHITECTURE CHART?

Tags: architecture, uml, diagram

My team project for a CS software architecture class has submitted an "architecture chart" for our project. We are designing an online DAW (digital audio workstation).

I emailed the chart we made and sent it to the professor for suggestions but his only response was "This is not an architecture chart", so that wasn't really very helpful.

I'm pasting a link to the chart below so that everybody can view it.
http://www.webkam.us/images/ArchChart.png

If anyone has any ideas about how to improve this or if anyone can provide a good example of what a correct architecture chart contain, please respond and let me know!

Thank you!
Kameron

Comment: He probably meant some kind of UML diagram (a components diagram or deployment diagram).

Answer (score 1):

Some of the common best practices for documenting software architectures, off the top of my head...

1. Diagrams should express a specific view (also called a perspective in some texts) and be clearly labeled as to what view the diagram shows.  (e.g. is this dynamic, static, or physical?  Alternatively.. component & connector, module, or allocation?)
2. Only on view should be shown in a diagram.  For example, a database cannot connect to a code package.  One is a run time structure while the other is a static/code structure.
3. Notations should be clearly defined, generally in a legend.  Even if you are using a "standard" notation such as something from UML.
4. Notations should be consistent, at least internally to the diagram if not the entire documentation set.  This means that a box or a dotted line, for example, in one diagram represents the same element or relation as in other diagrams.
5. Multiple views should be used to convey different granularities of abstraction.  An architecture description will consist of multiple views, at a minimum one for each of the perspectives.
6. The responsibilities for elements and relations should be clearly articulated, generally in an "element-responsibility catalog."  I like to create a table that describes the responsibilities for the various elements and relations in a diagram in more detail.  For example, "the database is responsible for persistent storage of user information."
7. Descriptive prose, including rationale, should describe the key decisions that were made (and generally but not necessarily depicted in a diagram) and provide rationale explaining why the decisions were made including alternatives not considered.  In the best case there will be a clear connection back to articulated architectural drivers.  For example, "we chose to use caching library X to support performance quality attribute scenario XYZ..."

See "[Documenting Software Architecture: Views and Beyond](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321552687)" for the "definitive" reference.  If you want to use UML to document your architecture, see Part II of "[Just Enough Software Architecture: A risk-Driven Approach](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0984618104)" for a good treatment of the subject. There may be relevant chapters online of each book but they are worth owning.

To critique your specific diagram based on the above best practices....

- No legend, what to boxes, lines, and circles mean?  Is there a difference between a dotted line, arrow, and flat line?
- What is the perspective?  I see layers, clients, servers, and possibly code modules all referenced.  You likely have mixed perspectives.
- Mixed granularities of abstraction -- first, a "layer" can't use a "client" (one is static and the other dynamic though I'm guessing you intended to denote a sort of hierarchic relation?).  Each level of the tree might be a different view, showing finer granularity of your abstraction.
- No rationale or descriptive prose.
- No understanding of elements or their responsibilities.

If you were going for a UML diagram I recommend clearly labeling what diagram you are using and still including a legend for the notation.  Not everyone who will read your document has memorized all the UML diagramming notations.

On the positive side, it seems like you probably have a good understanding of the system, you just need some help figuring out how to write it all down using architecture best practices!